# Building Custom Platform on ElasticBeanstalk Packer Error

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, packer

I am trying to build a custom platform using the provided example (NodePlatform_Ubuntu) at
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/custom-platforms.html#custom-platforms-pda

I installed EB CLI (my OS is MacOSX El Captain):

```
➜  custom-platform ebp --version 
EB CLI 3.10.1 (Python 2.7.1)
```

For some reason, EB CLI insists on using Python 2.7.1 instead of the already installed Python 3.x (python3 command works), but this shouldn't matter according to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install.html it supports Python 2.7

While "ebp init" works perfectly. the "ebp create" fails.

```
➜  custom-platform ebp create
Creating application version archive "app-170427_145319".
Uploading custom-platform/app-170427_145319.zip to S3. This may take a while.
Upload Complete.
Note: An environment called 'eb-custom-platform-builder-packer' has been created in order to build your application. This environment will not automatically be terminated and it does have a cost associated with it. Once your platform creation has completed you can terminate this builder environment using the command 'eb terminate'.
INFO: createPlatform is starting.
INFO: Initiated platform version creation for 'custom-platform/1.0.2'.
INFO: Creating Packer builder environment 'eb-custom-platform-builder-packer'.
ERROR: Packer environment eb-custom-platform-builder-packer is not available, current status: terminated.
INFO: Failed to create platform version 'custom-platform/1.0.2'.
```

This is the error:

```
ERROR: Packer environment eb-custom-platform-builder-packer is not available, current status: terminated.
```

More logs (debug mode):

```
2017-04-27 14:19:55,698 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : Response: {u'Events': [{u'PlatformArn': 'arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-west-2:107875334514:platform/custom-platform/1.0.1', u'Message': "Failed to create platform version 'custom-platform/1.0.1'.", u'Severity': 'INFO', u'EventDate': datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 27, 11, 19, 52, 84000, tzinfo=tzutc()), u'RequestId': 'f762956d-2b3a-11e7-8cd7-c96ae1e26915'}, {u'PlatformArn': 'arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-west-2:107875334514:platform/custom-platform/1.0.1', u'Message': 'Packer environment eb-custom-platform-builder-packer is not available, current status: terminated.', u'Severity': 'ERROR', u'EventDate': datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 27, 11, 19, 51, 861000, tzinfo=tzutc()), u'RequestId': 'f762956d-2b3a-11e7-8cd7-c96ae1e26915'}], 'ResponseMetadata': {'date': 'Thu, 27 Apr 2017 11:19:52 GMT', 'RetryAttempts': 0, 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'RequestId': '6f7dcea9-2b3b-11e7-8cd7-c96ae1e26915'}}
ERROR: Packer environment eb-custom-platform-builder-packer is not available, current status: terminated.
INFO: Failed to create platform version 'custom-platform/1.0.1'.
```

Note that the app-170427_145319.zip is successfully uploaded to S3.

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is was failing with instance profile(role) aws-elasticbeanstalk-custom-platform-ec2-role not getting necessary role inline policy attached to it.

Because of lot of modifications and changes, **apparently due to an EB CLI bug**, the instance profile got corrupted and was not taking InstanceProfile ARN when tried to create a profile with same name "aws-elasticbeanstalk-custom-platform-ec2-role".

So, we went ahead and created a new one named "custom-platform" and attached necessary inline policy permissions I have mentioned in the case.

Once that IAM issues are sorted, we went onto packer bundle,did "ebp init" and then ran "ebp create" but with -ip flag and used this instance profile custom-platform, as in

```
ebp create -ip custom-platform
```